# Ninject with Entity Framework in a base controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to use Ninject in ASP.NET MVC project. Here is my plan to use entity framework for my project-

```
//Web.config 
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyTestDbEntities" connectionString="...." />
</connectionStrings>

//Base controller
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly MyTestDbEntities Db;
    public BaseController() { }
    public BaseController(MyTestDbEntities context)
    {
        this.Db = context;
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Db.Students.Add(new Student() { StudentName="test"});
        Db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

I would like to use Ninject as follows-

```
kernel.Bind<MyTestDbEntities>().To<BaseController>().InRequestScope();
```

But it says-

```
The type 'NinjectTest.BaseController' cannot be used as type parameter 
'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 
'IBindingToSyntax<MyTestDbEntities>.To<TImplementation>()'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'NinjectTest.BaseController' 
to 'NinjectTest.Models.MyTestDbEntities'.
```

Would you please suggest me how can I configure Ninject to work in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what typically occurs is you bind an interface to a concrete Type that implements it, i.e.:

```
kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServiceImpl>();
```

you do not need to create a binding to be able to inject the service into every  consumer (i.e., `BaseController`). you can use the binding anywhere by asking for it in the constructor (contructor injection), or decorating a property with `[Inject]` (property injection, or setter injection)

in your example, you would need to create a binding for your DbContext:

```
kernel.Bind<MyTestDbEntities>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

and then it will be injected into your Controller constructors, but all Controllers that derive from BaseController will need to have that contructor that asks for the DbContext as a parameter

```
public HomeController(MyTestDbEntities db) : base(db) { }
```

however, be aware that you are creating a dependency on a concrete implementation (the DbContext), which sort of defeats the purpose of Dependency Injection.